# LoopbackJS static files expires

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm working with the latest LoopbackJS which enables files to be served from the `/client` folder, which I believe uses express server-static.

The default setup in the middleware.json is

```
 "files": {
    "loopback#static": {
        "params": "$!../client"
    }
 },
```

Is there any way I can modify this to set a relatively long expires header to everything it servers?

Comment: Assuming you are running loopback behind a webserver like nginx, cache control can be set from the webserver config, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a middleware in a boot script to set appropriate expiry headers.

However, I tend to move all the static files out of loopback and serve them through a web server like Nginx (unless any of these static files needs authorization to be accessed). I setup required headers in Nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To add an example to @abskmj's answer here is the solution I went with.

Inside `/server/server.js` I added a `use` to add expiry headers to everything except the API output

```
app.start = function() {

    ...

    // cache everything for at least 4h
    app.use(/^\/(?!api|anyother).*$/, function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=24000');
        next();
    });

    ...

};
```